# New tab with wheel mouse button

Tags: tabulator

I'm learning JS and Tabulator, and I wish to add to my tabulators the option for open a new tab a link with the wheel mouse button. I've read how to do it with left and right click, but I don't see the wheel mouse button.

```
// For left

table.on("rowClick", function(e, row){
    //e - the click event object
    //row - row component
});


// For right

table. On("rowContext", function(e, row){
    //e - the click event object
    //row - row component
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the browsers default context menu form appearing.
});
```